# Enumerations within a struct - C vs C++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, struct, enums

I'm trying to use Enums within a struct, this compiles and works fine with `gcc`.
But the same code when compiled with `g++` throws an error.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct foo
{
    enum {MODE1, MODE2, MODE3} mode;
    enum {TYPE1, TYPE2} type;
};
void bar(struct foo* bar)
{
    bar->mode = MODE1;
}

int main()
{
    struct foo* foo = (struct foo*) malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    bar(foo);
    printf("mode=%d\n",foo->mode);
}
```

Output obtained with `gcc`:

```
 $ gcc foo.c
 $ ./a.out
 mode=0
```

Output obtained with `g++`:

```
 $ g++ foo.c
 foo.c: In function ‘void bar(foo*)’:
 foo.c:11: error: ‘MODE1’ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Hooray! Someone who understands that C and C++ are (very) different languages! (Of course I'm talking about the compiler :P)

Comment: sure they are different, there are many differences.

Comment: @Manu343726: Would you be happy if I modified the title as `gcc vs g++` instead of `c vs c++` :)

Comment: Your title is fine. What happens is that often people think there is a language called C/C++, with one set of rules :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`MODE1` is in the scope of `foo`, so you need

```
bar->mode = foo::MODE1;
```

Note that if you want to access the enum types without a scope, you would need to declare them so. For example:

```
typedef enum {MODE1, MODE2, MODE3} MODE;
typedef enum {TYPE1, TYPE2} TYPE;

struct foo
{
    MODE mode;
    TYPE type;
};
```

Comment: thanks. Makes sense. But how can I get away without explicitly telling the compiler that `MODE1` belongs to `foo`. I cannot do a `#define MODE1 foo::MODE1`. That would violate the foo definition. Basically I want to minimize `C++` style of coding in my `C` code :)

Comment: For C/C++ compatibility you would need to move the enums outside the struct.

Comment: @arunmoezhi I'm not sure I follow. You don't want to code C++, but you want to compile as C++? That is going to be very painful.

Comment: @PaulR: I don't understand. I need the enums to be part of that struct.

Comment: @juanchopanza: As I said I wanted to minimize `C++`. The only other place in my code where I use `C++` is when I have some atomic variables which use Intel TBB which doesn't support C. Of course I'm completely ok with using `foo:MODE1`. But I was hoping there could be a way to avoid the `foo::`

Comment: @arunmoezhi Then you can follow Paul R's suggestion.

Comment: @arunmoezhi Yes, exactly.

Comment: @PaulR: Can you post your suggestion as answer. I think your answer is also equally good.

Comment: @juanchopanza: shouldn't you add a `typedef` before `enum`. I got a compile error without `typedef`

Comment: @arunmoezhi Yes, that's right, thanks. I don't write C very often these days.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51987/discussion-between-arunmoezhi-and-juanchopanza)