# How to access c++ enum in C file

Tags: c++, c, enums

I am unable to find same question on this site, hence asking. I want to know how to access enum type from C file which is declared inside a class. Consider following example:

test1.h

```
class abc
{
  public:
    enum mode
    {
      ENTER_MODE = 0,
      EXIT_MODE = 1
    };
}
```

test2.h

```
abc::mode test_mode();
```

test2.c

```
abc::mode test_mode()
{
  if (some_condition)
  {
    return abc::ENTER_MODE;
  }
  else
  {
    return abc::EXIT_MODE;
  }
}
```

This doesn't compile. Any suggestion ?

Comment: What compile error are you seeing?  Are you including test1.h inside test2.h?

Comment: `test2.c` should be `test2.cpp` - you have to compile this as C++, not C.

Comment: yes i am including... compiler is giving warnings which are related to other files which are included in test1.cpp.. this is strange

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462307/enums-inside-a-struct-c-vs-c

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using classes with C. Instead, just use structures (structures in C++ support many of the features of classes). In this example code (disregard if my assumption is wrong), there is no need for restricting the scope of the enumeration to within a class.

Ideally, you should save these as .cpp files and compile as C++. What does the compilation error say?

Answer (score -1):

End the class definition with a semicolon and declare as:

```
enum abc::mode test_mode();
```

try this one (this one compiles) ok:

```
class abc
{
  public:
    enum mode
    {
      ENTER_MODE = 0,
      EXIT_MODE = 1
    };
};

enum abc::mode test_mode()
{
    bool some_condition=false; // or something
  if (some_condition)
  {
    return abc::ENTER_MODE;
  }
  return abc::EXIT_MODE;
}
```

Comment: @JensGustedt but class is used, do you mean C?

Comment: Agree with @PaulR filename should be .cpp, not .c